# What would be the appropriate technique for typesetting a "where" list of variable specifications after an equation?

Tags: equations, amsmath, align

I'm often finding I need to lay out an equation in a manner resembling the
following source:

```
\begin{align*}
    x = y + z
\end{align*}
where $y = $ the value of $y$;
      $z = $ the value of $z$.
```

Of course, that precise code puts all the "where" definitions on the one line,
as parts of the same paragraph. What would be the best way to specify that
list, such that it appears similarly to that above source, i.e., like this?

```
      x = y + z
where y = the value of y;
      z = the value of z.
```

Preferably, the equals signs in the list would be aligned with the one in the
actual equation.

Comment: I've added [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)'s `\shortintertext` as a slightly condensed alternative.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `\intertext` macro to intersperse regular paragraph-aligned text within an `align` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
From this, it is easy to see that
\begin{align*}
    x &= y + z \\
\intertext{where}
    y &= \text{the value of $y$}; \\
    z &= \text{the value of $z$}.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

This maintains the original `align` alignment and doesn't require any fiddling with boxes (another way of making sure the alignment remains the same).

---

[`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) provides some extensions to `amsmath` functionality, including `\shortintertext`, yielding a slightly condensed display:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% Automatically loaded by mathtools
%\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\begin{document}
From this, it is easy to see that
\begin{align*}
    x &= y + z \\
\shortintertext{where}
    y &= \text{the value of $y$}; \\
    z &= \text{the value of $z$}.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is also `\shortintertext` with the `\mathtools` package which produces tighter spacing.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Thanks - I've added a visual of the difference.