# Math list - equation, operands specification

Tags: math-mode, lists

What I'd like to produce:

```
Y = A + B + C + D
where:
A........amount of whatever
B........foobar amounts whatever
C........foo
D........you name it
```

I am working with this equation:

```
\[Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 E_i + \beta_2 T_i + \sum_{j = 1}^{32} \beta_{j+2} M_{ij} + u_i \]
```

Similar question (yet not the one): [What would be the appropriate technique for typesetting a "where" list of variable specifications after an equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45928/what-would-be-the-appropriate-technique-for-typesetting-a-where-list-of-variab)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Why isn't the linked question appropriate? I don't see how the leader dots can improve the appearance.

Comment: Hi there. See the answer by Torbjørn T.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a suggestion with a `tabular`. I specify the width of the first column, set the contents in math mode, and fill the remaining with dots. The `array` package is necessary.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\[
Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 E_i + \beta_2 T_i + \sum_{j = 1}^{32} \beta_{j+2} M_{ij} + u_i
\]
where

\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{$}p{3em}<{$\dotfill}@{}l}
\beta_0 & amount of this \\
\beta_1 & amount of that
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a kind of table of contents try to write

```
\noindent A\dotfill amount of whatever     \hspace{3cm} \\
\noindent B\dotfill foobar amounts whatever\hspace{3cm}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it not full wide? Say minimum of 4 dots but still aligned with the rest.