# writing the details about variables of a equation (math) in IEEEtran

Tags: math-mode, ieeetran

I think that this is a very basic question but i couldn't find any answer. I have written the following equation in latex:

```
\begin{equation}
U= \frac{\bar{X}_1 -\bar{X}_2}{\sqrt{\frac{S^2_1}{n_1}+\frac{S^2_1}{n_1}}}
\end{equation}
```

I want to write the variable names also e.g.

`Where,`

`\bar{X}_1` `= mean of first dataset` and so on.

**Problem:**

I tried suggestion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45928/what-would-be-the-appropriate-technique-for-typesetting-a-where-list-of-variab) but then i facing another problem. The details about my variable are a little loner so the text is touching the margin as shown in the image below:

[image]

**PS:** I am writing in `IEEEtran`

**My code for whole equation:**

```
\begin{align*}  
    U &= \frac{\bar{X}_1 -\bar{X}_2}{\sqrt{\frac{S^2_1}{n_1}+\frac{S^2_1}
{n_1}}}
\intertext{where}
    \bar{X}_1 &= \text{mean of correctly recognized In-direction distractors}; \\
    \bar{X}_2 &= \text{mean of correctly recognized Out-direction distractors}; \\
    S_1 &= \text{variance of correctly recognized In-direction distractors}; \\
    S_2 &= \text{variance of correctly recognized Out-direction distractors}.
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Do you mean something like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45928/what-would-be-the-appropriate-technique-for-typesetting-a-where-list-of-variab?

Comment: I think this question is related [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39515/is-there-a-way-to-set-math-mode-font-non-italic)

Comment: Also related: [Description list for equation's terms](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/169928)  This should solve your long lines problem.

Comment: Sorry, nothing helped. I am able to bring `where`. My problem is that the text of `where` is touching the image as shown in the image above. How to get rid of it?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: ok, i have updated the code which i am using. I am writing in `IEEEtran`

Comment: Generally it's always best if you post *complete* documents, i.e. starting with `\documentclass`, ending with `\end{document}`, so that we can just copy-paste and compile the entire thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `tabularx` instead of `align`:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
U= \frac{\bar{X}_1 -\bar{X}_2}{\sqrt{\frac{S^2_1}{n_1}+\frac{S^2_1}{n_1}}}
\end{equation}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{$}r<{$} @{${}={}$} X}
\bar{X}_1 & mean of correctly recognized In-direction distractors; \\
\bar{X}_2 & mean of correctly recognized Out-direction distractors; \\
S_1 & variance of correctly recognized In-direction distractors; \\
S_2 & variance of correctly recognized Out-direction distractors.
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The question [which I linked in the comment above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169928/description-list-for-equations-terms) works fine here too.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\SetLabelAlign{myright}{\hss\llap{$#1$}}
\newlist{where}{description}{1}
\setlist[where]{labelwidth=2cm,labelsep=0.5em,itemsep=0pt,
                        leftmargin=!,align=myright,font=\normalfont}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
U= \frac{\bar{X}_1 -\bar{X}_2}{\sqrt{\frac{S^2_1}{n_1}+\frac{S^2_1}{n_1}}}
\end{equation}
Where:
\begin{where}
\item[\bar{X}_1 =] mean of correctly recognized In-direction distractors some text filled for this line and in to the next line; 
\item[\bar{X}_2 =] mean of correctly recognized Out-direction distractors; 
\item[S_1 =] variance of correctly recognized In-direction distractors; 
\item[S_2 =] variance of correctly recognized Out-direction distractors.
\end{where}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want to type `=` in every item, replace `\SetLabelAlign{myright}` with this:

```
\SetLabelAlign{myright}{\hss\llap{$#1 =$}}
```

Comment: Thanks, i used the above answer which worked perfect in my case :)